# Eloquent ORM relationship always return null in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 Models:

MonHoc Model:

```
class MonHoc extends Model{
   protected $table='monhoc' ;
   protected $fillable = [
      'mamh', 'phuongthucgiangday', 'tenmh','tinchitichluy','tinchihocphi','hockydenghi',
   ];

   public function monTienQuyet(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\MonTQ','montq_id','id');
   }

   public function monTuyChon(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\MonTC','montc_id','id');
   }
}
```

MonTC model:

```
class MonTC extends Model{
   protected $table='monhoc_tuychon' ;
   protected $fillable = [
      'monhoc_id', 'montc_id',
   ];
   public function monhoc(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\MonHoc','monhoc_id');
   }
}
```

MonTQ model:

```
class MonTQ extends Model{
   protected $table='montienquyet' ;
   protected $fillable = [
      'monhoc_id', 'montq_id',
   ];    
   public function monhoc(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\MonHoc','monhoc_id');
   }
}
```

but when I use MonHoc model in controller:

```
public function test(MonHoc $monhoc){
   $mon=$monhoc->monTienQuyet->toSql();
   dd($mon);
}
```

it show SQL

```
select * from `montienquyet` where `montienquyet`.`montq_id` is null and `montienquyet`.`montq_id` is not null
```

It show null in MySQL because the where clause is the opposite. I don't know why the model export this SQL!

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

For `hasMany`:

```
return $this->hasMany(MonTC::class, 'montc_id');
```

For `belongsTo`:

```
return $this->belongsTo(MonHoc::class, 'monhoc_id');
```

Another solution is:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\MonTC', 'montc_id');
```

And

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\MonHoc', 'monhoc_id');
```

Comment: please add `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; ` before the class started.

Comment: also add below code after class declaration:


`protected $fillable = [ 'monhoc_id','montc_id'];`

Comment: I've added all of them

Comment: Will you please try this one : `return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\MonHoc');`
and `return $this->hasMany('App\Models\MonTC');`

Comment: just remove key from return statements.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
public function test(MonHoc $monhoc){
   $monhoc = $monhoc->find(1) //the id that exists
   $mon=$monhoc->monTienQuyet;
   dd($mon);
}
```